# Looking for the exact opposite use case as a Cell in Rust—Interior Immutability?

Tags: oop, rust, struct, field, immutability

I've learned a lot about `Cell<T>`, and it is very useful, but I currently have a struct along the lines of

```
struct User {
    username: String,
    pronouns: Cell<Option<Pronouns>>,
    email: Cell<Option<String>>
}
```

and some more fields that all use `Cell<T>`. As you can see, pretty much every field in this struct *except for* username is made interior-mutable through the use of Cell, and now I'm wondering if there is something out there that allows for the exact opposite approach so I don't have to wrap nearly every single one of `User`'s fields in Cell. Something like this:

```
struct User {
    username: AntiCell<String>,
    pronouns: Option<Pronouns>,
    email: Option<String>
}

// Created users will be mutable.
```

For now, using a million `Cell`s is perfectly fine, but I want to know if there's some way to tend to the minority here.

Comment: Needing this many cells in an otherwise-POD structure smells of bad design somewhere else in the program. If something else needs interior mutability in `User`, shouldn't they have a `RefCell<User>` or something like that? Why does the interior mutability need to "infect" `User`?

Comment: I fully agree with @cdhowie. Your `User` should probably not have any `Cell`s at all. What are you trying to achieve with it? Why are those `Cell`s needed, and could that code be changed instead?

Comment: @Finomnis It doesn't (unless you do that yourself). `Cell` is a zero-cost abstraction.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I just realized that there's no real point to `Cell<String>` ... as `String` doesn't implement `Copy`, `Cell` doesn't provide `get()`, so what's the point of it in the first place?

Comment: @Finomnis You can use `take()`, mutate it, then `set()` it back.

Answer (score 1):

This requirement doesn't really make sense.

Suppose you have an ***immutable*** reference to a value of type `User`. Here, you can modify the fields wrapped in `Cell`, but not the one that isn't. So you don't need `AntiCell` in this case.

Now suppose you have a ***mutable*** reference. Yes, you can mutate all fields, but this would be the case even if `AntiCell` existed:

```
struct User {
    username: AntiCell<String>,
    pronouns: Option<Pronouns>,
    email: Option<String>
}

fn foo(user: &mut User) {
    *user = User {
        // replace the immutable field with a new value
        username: AntiCell::new(String::from("Something else")),
        // move the remaining mutable fields from the original
        ..user
    };
}
```

As long as you have mutable access to a value, you can change any or all of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reduce the number of `Cell`s, you can move the other fields into another struct:

```rs
struct User {
    username: String,
    details: Cell<Details>,
}

struct Details {
    pronouns: Option<Pronouns>,
    email: Option<String>
}
```

Comment: Note `RefCell` would be better here, because `Cell`s can only read and replace the whole value at once. Modifying a single field through a `Cell` requires some obnoxious gymnastics.